# Milliseconds timer performance / battery usage in Android

Tags: java, android, timer, android-handler

I'm building a simple timer that will display the milliseconds as well. Something like

**Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds**

I'm updating the `TextView` that displays the timer every millisecond, inside a `Handler` that calls itself every 1 millisecond:

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {            
      //calculate new time
      ...
      //update TextView
      ...
      timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);          
   }
};
```

My question is, will calling a `Handler` every 1 millisecond significantly affect the battery usage of the app?

Is there any better approach (performance-wise) other than using a `Handler`?

I've checked multiple posts of timers and stopwatches implementations but they will either not display the milliseconds or they won't discuss about performance issues.

Comment: Android's view hierarchy is locked to a 60fps cycle starting with Android 4.1. You will not be updating the screen 1000 times per second.

Comment: Thanks, actually the TextView will be updated each second, however some other calculations will need to be updated every millisecond. Is there any performance / battery issue calling that handler every millisecond?

Comment: "Is there any performance / battery issue calling that handler every millisecond?" -- well, doing anything every millisecond has performance and battery issues. `Handler` itself will not present a problem.